# Use 'parse_query' filter to show posts that from multiple criteria

Tags: wp-query, filters, wp-admin

I am trying to filter the Posts page in the WordPress admin to show posts that meet the criteria for "A" -or- the criteria for "B". I've scoured documentation and can't find a good way to do this.

Details:
I've scoped user roles so that authors can only edit their own posts. However, I've added a custom field so that authors may select other authors to enable them to edit the post as well. This functionality works perfectly if I use one or the other in my 'parse_query' filter, but if I try to enable both the query thinks I want to show posts that fit ALL criteria (which is none).

For reference, here is my code (this is in functions.php):

```
add_filter('parse_query', 'show_appropriate_posts');
function show_appropriate_posts($query) {
    if ( strpos($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit.php') !== false ) {
        if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
            global $current_user;

            //Only list posts by this user (A).
            $query->set('author', $current_user->id);

            //List posts this user is "tagged" in (B).
            $query->set('meta_key', 'add_editing_permission_for');
            $query->set('meta_value', $current_user->id);
            $query->set('meta_compare', 'LIKE');

            //@TODO: Need to show posts that meet (A) -or- (B).
        }
    }
}
```

Again, both (A) and (B) are working when run alone.

Comment: After more research, I'm thinking I might need a custom SQL query. If that's the case, I'd appreciate any help integrating one with the above filter.

Comment: Have a look at [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) (to replae `meta_key`, `meta_value` and `meta_compare`), you may be able to do something with that.

Comment: Actually, disregard my previous comment, I don't think you can do it that way. Hopefully I've provided you with an answer though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore my comment about `meta_query`. Not only does it not work with `$query->set()`, you wouldn't be able to control the critical "A **OR** B" requirement of the query.

Instead, I believe what you require is possible via a combination of both the `pre_get_posts` action hook and `posts_where` filter hook as follows.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_show_appropriate_posts');
function my_show_appropriate_posts($query){

    if(strpos($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit.php') !== false) :

        if(!current_user_can('manage_options')) :

            /** Unset so that we can control exactly where this part of the query is included */
            $query->set('author', null);

            /** Ensure that the relevant tables required for a meta query are included */
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'add_editing_permission_for',
                    'value'     => 'dummy', // This cannot be empty because of a bug in WordPress
                    'compare'   => '='
                )
            ));

            /** Call the filter to amend the '$where' portion of the query */
            add_filter('posts_where', 'my_custom_posts_where');

        endif;

    endif;

}

function my_custom_posts_where( $where = '' ){

    global $wpdb;

    /** Add our required conditions to the '$where' portion of the query */
    $where.= sprintf(
        ' AND ( %1$s.post_author = %2$s OR ( %3$s.meta_key = "add_editing_permission_for" AND %3$s.meta_value = %2$s ) )',
        $wpdb->posts,
        get_current_user_id(),
        $wpdb->postmeta
    );

    /** Remove the filter to call this function, as we don't want it any more */
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'my_custom_posts_where');

    return $where;

}
```

**Recommended reading**

- The **`pre_get_posts` action hook** - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts
- The **`posts_where` filter hook** - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Comment: Thanks for this- with some very slight modifications this did what I needed (changed the first AND in your sprintf to be an OR, and edited the meta_query). Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I am curious as to why you had to change `AND` to `OR` though? The idea is that you are telling the query "(meet all previous conditions) `AND` (ensure the post author is the current user `OR` ensure the current user has been authorised to edit the post)". By changing it to `OR` you are ignoring all other conditions, such as the post type - so for example, you may find that users who have authored pages see them on the list, not just posts.

Comment: Also, I see that someone else had rejected you edit of my answer. The reason for that is because it doesn't really 'fix' anything.  The `meta_query` for instance doesn't make any difference (as far as I know), you just have to pass one to `$query->set()` to ensure the relevent joins are made.  And with changing `AND` to `OR`, if you could explain why you did that in the comments for other users that would be great, and from there I can edit the answer if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: TBH, I thought I fixed it, but it was only the illusion of working- haha. The ```OR``` made everything show up which looked like it was fixed. I'm actually still stuck on this- I'm certain your code will work, but I haven't been able to figure out the specifics yet. For some reason the rest of the SQL is not working right (and I don't know why because it looks exactly like what I want). I'm glad my edit got rejected actually, because it would have led other people down the wrong path (to where I am now).

Comment: It has something to do with the ```meta_key``` side of the SQL query. Even if I try to query for that alone I don't get any results. The ```$query->set``` from the first function seems to have something to do with it- I feel like it might not be prepping those keys right? Oh- you'll need to remove the 2nd call to ```add_filter('posts_where', 'my_custom_posts_where');``` in your answer- otherwise it triggers on all posts (on the frontend too)- that line should only appear inside the first function.

Comment: Why are you adding the filter twice (once inside the callback and once in the global scope)? From a quick look it then will run on _every_ query. +1 for the rest of the answer :)

Comment: Good spot, I've removed the one from the global scope.

Comment: Ok I got it working now. It's embarrassing, but the only additional change you need in your answer is the ```'='``` after ```'dummy'``` needs to be a ```'!='```. It was a roundabout way of finding it using phpmyadmin to test SQL queries, but at the very least it's all good now.